# disk2vhd of working IIS7 Web Server - cannot connect from internet

Tags: iis-7, hyper-v

Did a disk2vhd of our online production Windows Server 2008R2 server that runs an IIS7 Web Server that serves up our business application:

- Launched the VHDX in a Hyper-V VM on a new Windows Server 2016 server.
- Gave the VM its own public IP address.
- Repointed one of our unused domain names in DNS to point to the VM's public IP address.
- In the VM - edited the IIS7 site's bindings - removed the old bindings - and added the bindings for the new domain name.
- Port 80 is open to the VM on our Cisco firewall.
- The VM's Windows Firewall is turned *OFF*.

*We can ping/RDP/SSH/etc. the VM with no issues!*

The problem is that ***we cannot connect to the IIS web server at all*** - we get *"Refused Connection"* [ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED] errors - (*NOT* 404 errors).

localhost... We cannot connect to the IIS Server in the VM via localhost (gives a 404 error) - *but since we cannot connect via localhost in the production server either, I don't think that matters* (also gives a 404 error).

Running out of ideas... help?

**[...edit... IIS site binding information for this new server VM]**

Remember, this VM is a copy of our real server - so...

I deleted all of the previous domain specific bindings for the IIS site.

I kept the standard bindings (but changed localhost private IP address):

```
type:              host name:        port: binding info.:
---                ---               ---   ---
http               localhost         80    10.10.10.99
net.tcp                                    808:*
net.pipe                                   *
net.msmq                                   localhost
msmq.formatname                            localhost
```

And I added the entries for binding this copy of the IIS site to the new domain name - (not worried about https yet):

```
http                domain.com       80   *
http                www.domain.com   80   *
```

**[...edit... Hyper-V network]**

In Hyper-v manager we created a new "External" virtual switch.

We added a "Network Adapter" to the VM, but never got anywhere... so we changed to a "Legacy Network Adapter" and tried everything again... and still no IIS connection.

And, as I said... all other network services that we need to use against our server (RDP, etc.) work... that makes me believe it's only IIS that is the problem.

CBruce

Comment: "In the VM - edited the IIS7 site's bindings - removed the old bindings - and added the bindings for the new domain name." What is the new binding? Never post a broken question that nobody can answer. If you have no idea what is site binding, run the report and edit the question to include it, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

Found it...

Our consultant was trying to test with localhost after we first loaded the VM - (he didn't know at that time that the production server did not work with localhost).

He forgot that he had changed the HTTP IP listener from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1 while testing. Therefore, a connection attempt was never getting to the IIS Server - it was being blocked at the interface.